# Manga about a guy who receives a power suit in the mail

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember reading a manga about a a guy that sits in his room all the time, hardly ever coming out, and then receives a suit in the mail that gives him super strength and abilities. He goes around jumping on buildings, having fun at first, then finds out there are other people with different kinds of suits and they were doing experiments to see how it can push the body or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, in roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Junk: Record of the Last Hero](https://otakuusamagazine.com/junk-record-of-the-last-hero/)*

> Hiro (“hero?”), a socially withdrawn, idol-singer-obsessed teenage hikikomori, receives a mysterious tokusatsu-style superhero suit in the mail and uses it to go on nightly rampages, leaping on rooftops and beating up bullies (and, in one excellent chapter, tracking down and threatening people who said bad things about him on the Internet). While journalists and police speculate about the vigilante’s identity, Hiro battles another possessor of a “Junk” suit.
>
> But fighting is only an afterthought; the real purpose of the series is to show how Hiro uses his power, and it isn’t pretty. As a main character he is so unsympathetic, such a cold-hearted jerk to everyone around him, that the reader longs for the series to end with him getting his ass kicked rather than the more likely outcome of redemption. The reason why this creep received a “Junk” suit remains shrouded in mystery (which is good because there’s probably no satisfying explanation), and instead of criminal masterminds or supervillains, Hiro and his friends find themselves fighting disappointingly mundane molesters, stalkers, and rapists. (Starting in Volume 2, there’s enough seinen-manga sex and perversion that if the hero said “my junk,” you wouldn’t be sure what he’s talking about.)Meanwhile, characters debate pretentious superhero-philosophy in the midst of combat (“So, which did you choose to become? A god? A devil?”).

Found with a search for `manga hikikomori suit "in the mail"` (*hikikomori* is a Japanese term used for socially withdrawn shut-ins).

Comment: That was it!! Thanks